# How to mock router.navigateByUrl(...).then in Angular with Karma and Jasmine

Tags: angular, mocking, karma-jasmine

My problem is pretty simple, I use navigateByUrl() then then() in this way:

```
this.router
.navigateByUrl(PAGE1, {
  skipLocationChange: true
})
.then(() => {
  this.router.navigate([PAGE2]);
});
```

and I mock navigate, navigateByUrl and then this way:

```
const mockRouter = {
  navigate: () => {},
  navigateByUrl(url: string) { return url; },
  then: () => {}
};
```

It works well for navigate and navigateByUrl but it doesn't work for then and I don't know how to mock this function. How can I proceed?

Comment: For that to work `navigateByUrl` has to return a *promise*. In general, your test doubles need to match the implementations of the things they're replacing (and you should use the type system to tell you that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to jonrsharpe advise i found the solution.
The solution was to mock navigateByUrl this way:

```
navigateByUrl: () => {
    return {
      then: () => {}
    }
  }
```